# Can we point file up-loader to always upload from a specific folder

Tags: html, file-upload

My requirement is when I click on Choose File(input type="file") it should take me to a specified path always e.g. C:\Desktop. Can we do this?

HTML code for upload

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="formsub">
        <label class="formsub-item">
            <input name="file" type="file">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller code for upload

```
@PostMapping("/upload") // //new annotation since 4.3
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {

    //file type check
    //some operations
    return "index"; 
}
```

Comment: What if I don't have a `C:`?

Comment: its an internal app.. there will be one shared location which we have to point

Comment: You cannot control a standard browser's file input dialog for security purposes. This has nothing to do with the back end; browsers don't care what they're talking to. I have re-tagged appropriately.